# Join queries from two different databases on the same server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two DB's on the same server. I have two simple select queries for each DB which work correctly. But, when combined into a join, they fail. I want to fix this.

Pseudocode -

```
select *
from (select columns from DB1) as D1
inner join 
select *
from (select columns from DB2 where some valid condition) as D2
on D1.column1 = D2.column1
```

Error -

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'. (ie second "outer" select)
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'on'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jeez - all i had to do was this -

```
select *
from (select columns from DB1) as D1
inner join 
--select *
--from 
(select columns from DB2 where some valid condition) as D2
on D1.column1 = D2.column1
```

See the commented lines. Remove them and it should work.

Note, to include columns selected from D2, put the D2 columns in the uppermost select statement.

```
select col1b, col2c
from (select col1a, col1b from DB1) as D1
inner join 
--select *
--from 
(select col2a, col2b, col2c from DB2 where some valid condition) as D2
on D1.col1a = D2.col2a
```

This will display col1b and col2c.

Comment: I can accept my answer in two days...great. Source = google: sql server join two select statements. Link - http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=101449

Comment: That will be great, as long as two conditions are met:  (1) all values exist in both results, otherwise, the "inner join" will drop any values of "column1" that do not exist on both sides.  If this is a problem, can you pick one of the results that has *all* column1 values, use it as the driver (the FROM table), and then use LEFT OUTER JOIN instead of INNER JOIN.  (2) If any values of column1 occur multiple times in both results, then you'll get values of results-rows... if it doesn't happen often or the mess is understandable, then this is just a cosmetic concern.

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from DataBaseName.ShemaName.TableName1 D1 inner join  DataBaseName.ShemaName.TableName2 D2
on D1.column1 = D2.column1
WHERE Somecondition
```

Comment: I may be wrong, but for MSSQL I think you would need 2 dots between the database name and the table name for where the schema would be.

Comment: Nope in sql server a fully qualified name for a column is like 
ServerName.DatabaseName.SchemaName.TableName.ColumnName

Comment: Indeed, but if the databases are in the instance, you can address them as DBNAme..TableName which will use the default schema - alternatively you could qualify (as you have edited your answer to show) as DBName.SchemaName.TableName.

Comment: While you can use .., you should use the schema name, usually your default is dbo. If you have another server, it should be a four-part name `Server.Database.Schema.Object`. Normally, `SELECT * FROM Database.Schema.Object ...`

Comment: I forgot to put schema name in my answer thanks for your question. But using DatabaseName..TableName is fine if your only referring to default schema dbo but for any other schema in a database you have to use fully qualified name

Comment: but this will join the whole tables, which i think will be inefficient. I want to join the results of two queries.

Comment: Join the result set of two queries you need to look at UNION or UNION ALL operators, which adds the result sets of two or more queries vertically, JOIN operator joins two or more tables horizontally.

Comment: I think UNION won't work because the two result sets have different number of columns.

Comment: in this case could you please edit your questions show us the structure of your both tables and show us the desired result set because with provided information its difficult to understand what exactly you are try to achieve with your query. Thank you

Comment: looks good if it does the job for you but your question was a bit misleading anyway good luck pal.